# How to move files safely in Sourceforge using interactive shell

Tags: sourceforge

I'm trying to tidy up my project's release files on Sourceforge using the interactive shell and the [Sourceforge wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Release%20Files%20for%20Download/) is not helpful at all.

The current structure for my project's files is similar to:

```
home
 \-frs
    \-project
         |-f
         | \-fo
         |    \-fooproject
         |          \- (contents same as fooproject below!)
         \-fooproject
               |-folder1
               |    |-v1.0
               |        \-file1.0.zip
               |    |-v2.0
               |        \-file2.0.zip
               \-folder2
                    |-v3.0
                    |   \-file3.0.zip
                    |-v4.0
                    |   \-file4.0.zip
```

I want to do some renaming/moving (just the folders - not the files) so it looks like this:

```
home
 \-frs
    \-project
         |-f
         | \-fo
         |    \-fooproject
         |          \- (contents same as fooproject below!)
         \-fooproject
               |-1.0
               |   \-file1.0.zip
               |-2.0
               |   \-file2.0.zip
               |-3.0
               |   \-file3.0.zip
               |-4.0
                   \-file4.0.zip
```

I tried doing this (with the `mv` command) and the folders appeared correctly on the SF website, but the files were missing (and the download latest file link was broken). So I reverted my changes and it's back to normal now.

Am I missing something? How am I meant to rename and move these folders? I'm a bit puzzled by the duplicate fooproject folders (I can't see any symbolic links) - I made my changes to the `home/frs/project/fooproject` directory.

I'm also concerned about losing the download history - I read somewhere that that's based on the filename, so I should be ok as long as I don't rename any files - is that correct?

**Update:**

So I tried it again and it looks like it just takes a minute and then the files appear (which is good), and the latest file link does update (also good), but the download stats reset to zero (not good!) and the changes aren't in synch with the mirrors (not sure how long this takes). So it appears the download stats are based on the full path, and renaming any folder resets the count for any files inside :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, you can move files around using the interactive shell, but:

- renaming any file/folder will reset the download stats for that file/folder (you can revert the change and the stats will still be there)
- it takes a while for a file move to be reflected on Sourceforge (give it at least 30 secs)

I contacted Sourceforge support and received the following response (hopefully they update their wiki to make this clearer).

```
Download stats are associated with the path and filename. So if you
move/rename a file the download stats for that particular file won't be
attached to the file anymore. That said, the counts will still apply to
the aggregate stats though (ie., total downloads per project).

Other than that, moving files/folders around should work as expected after
a short delay for items to sync (on the mirrors as you suggest, etc.)

As for the folders appearing empty, I'm not sure what happened there, if
(given the stats caveat), you still want to do this, give this another
try, and if the issue persists, please leave at least one folder in this
state and let us know so we can review.

Regards,
Chris Tsai, !SourceForge.net Support
```